# How can I select a piece of code to run from a <select> html tag PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a select drop down:

```
    <form action="member.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="80%">
    <tr>
        <td class="borderblack">Select Phone Type:
            <select name="phone_type">
                    <option value="escene" name="escene">Escene</option>
                    <option value="grandstream" name="grandstream">Grandstream</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="phone_typesub">
        </td>


        <td class="borderblack">
            <label for="file">Upload XML:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" >
        </td>   
</form>
```

Depending on the dropdown option selected i want to run a specific block of code Thats contained in a different file.  I was wondering if anyone could advise me. (There are 2 blocks of code in the php file )

Comment: Are both blocks of code in the same php page?

Comment: Do you want this code to be run when they submit the form, or when they click an option?  (POST or AJAX)

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any attempts in your question to solve the issue. We're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this in `member.php`:

```
if($_POST['phone_type']=='escene'){
    import 'escene_handler.php';       // run this if they selected 'escene'
}else if($_POST['phone_type']=='grandstream'){
    import 'grandstream_handler.php';  // run this if they selected 'grandstream'
}
```

That would be called when the form was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I think AJax is the best solution for this problem .

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    switch ($_POST['phone_type']) {
        case 'escene':
            // run your code when 'escene' is selected
            break;
        case 'grandstream':
            // run your code when 'grandstream' is selected
            break;
        default:
            // run default code, when non of the above is selected, or ignore
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['YourDropDownName']) && $_POST['YourDropDownName'] == "Option1Value")
{
    //do stuff here...
}
else if(isset($_POST['YourDropDownName']) && $_POST['YourDropDownName'] == "Option2Value")
{
    //do other stuff here...
}?>`
```

this could work.